# How to get orphaned text with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I have an html:

```
<span>This is the first text</span>
More text here 
Another line of text
<span>Text in the span</span>
<span>Another text in span</span>
This is another line
```

I want to get all the texts in order, something like this array:

```
[
"Span:This is the first text",
"More text here",
"Another line of text",
"Span:Text in the span",
"Span:Another text in span",
"This is another line",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a recursive method that takes your starting tag and iterates over its child nodes.  For each TextNode, print the contents.  For each Element, check it for child nodes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException
{
    //I put your HTML in the body tag in a local file
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("input/20160505.html"), "UTF-8");
    Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("body");
    Element rootTag = elements.get(0);
    printTextOfTag(rootTag);
}

public static void printTextOfTag(Element currentTag)
{
    List<Node> nodes = currentTag.childNodes();
    for(Node n : nodes)
    {
        if(n instanceof TextNode)
        {
            System.out.println(((TextNode)n).text());
        }
        else if(n instanceof Element)
        {
            printTextOfTag((Element)n);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
This is the first text

 More text here Another line of text 

Text in the span



Another text in span

 This is another line
```