# Gather text from HTML using java when there are no tags

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Im working with java to get text form a website. This website doesn't use tags such as `<p>` and `<h1>`. All of the text I'm looking for is under the class props ().I understand using jsoup I can select the class but then I don't know how to get the text.

Here's an example of the text:

```
div style="margin-bottom:8px;">Repulse Bay</div>
<div><div><b>Gross Area:</b> 5,051 sq.ft. (@ HK$ 67 p.s.f.)</div>
<div><b>Saleable Area:</b> 3,871 sq.ft. (@ HK$ 88 p.s.f.)</div></div>
<div><b>Bedrooms:</b> 3 (2-Ensuite)</div>
<div><b>Bathrooms:</b> 3.5</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get orphaned text with Jsoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915562/how-to-get-orphaned-text-with-jsoup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use same text() method.

```
doc.getElementsByClass( "cls-1" ).forEach( ele -> {

    System.out.println( ele.text() );
} );
```

Just you need use `getElementsByclass(<classname>)` and then iterate through the elements to get text from each node.

Comment: hi. just curious what type of data  "ele.text()" is. If I want to do stuff with data.

Comment: @DeanAllen the return type of the `text()` will be a String type data. You can check the documentation `public String text()`

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expressions here without `jsoup`.

```
String content = "<div><b>Saleable Area:</b> 3,871 sq.ft. (@ HK$ 88 p.s.f.)</div></div><div><b>Bedrooms:</b> 3 (2-Ensuite)</div>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
// Output
//@ HK$ 88 p.s.f.
//2-Ensuite
```

Or apply this regex to all text nodes with `jsoup`.