# How can I remove the html tags from an html file and get the text parts only?

Tags: java

I want to make a method so that it can remove the html tags from an html code and only keep the plain text parts. I have made a method myself and I guess it should work, but it doesnt. I have seen some solutions but most of them are using data types which I have not studied yet and we are not allowed to use them. So can someone look at my code and see what is the problem or provide me with another algorithm or solution? Thanks,
My current code is:

```
public String getPageContents() {
    String result = super.getPageContents();
    int length = result.length() - 1;
    String tempResult = "";
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        if ( result.charAt(i) == '>' ) {                
            int index = 0;              
            while ( result.charAt(index) != '<' ) {
                index++;
                tempResult = tempResult + result.substring(i, index );
            }
        }
    }
return tempResult;
```

Comment: This is Java, you need to tag your question as Java and remove the javascript tag.

Comment: This article may help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string.

Comment: @José Quinto Zamora: The SO question you selected as "duplicate" is JavaScript not Java.

Comment: How about you use java regular expression.
[Regex to strip HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075742/regex-to-strip-html-tags)

Comment: Very similar to this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915562/how-to-get-orphaned-text-with-jsoup/41916010#41916010

Comment: @NiK648 yah but the problem is we are not allowed to use stuff which we haven't studied yet.

Comment: @ProgrammersBlock yup similar but they are using other libraries we are not allowed to use. THankks

Comment: Then I think you need to update the question.  "we are not allowed to use them" to something like "we are not allowed to use third party jars, we have to hand-code this algorithm".  Clearly many people aren't getting this point.

Comment: Secondly, if you have to hand-code this algorithm, the question is too broad for StackOverflow.  You have to understand the HTML specification, escape characters, etc, which could lead to the question being too chatty.  You also make an errant request for an algorithm.  These are three points that we have flags for bad questions for.